# click and open a box while closing the other

Tags: jquery

I have a set of boxes, i don't know the exact number with the sub div set to display none:

```
  <div class="box">
     <div class="content">
         <div class="info" style="display: none;"></div>
     <div>
  <div>
  <div class="box">
     <div class="content">
         <div class="info" style="display: none;"></div>
     <div>
  <div>
  <div class="box">
     <div class="content">
         <div class="info" style="display: none;"></div>
     <div>
  <div>
```

I am looking for simple and correct jQuery to open animating (animating to a given fixed height and width) on a click a box, load its content and show it while closing by animating and taking height and width back to its original values previously opened boxes.

something like that but it isn't working:

```
$(function() {
   $(".box").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(".box .content .info").empty();
       $(".box").hide('slow');
       var url = this.href + " .content";
        $(".info", this).load(url, function() {
           $(".box", this).show('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my final solution with the html wrote in my first question:

```
$(".box").each(function() {
//we set needed variables
var item = $(this);
var thumb = $("a", item);
var infoBox = $(".info", item);
thumb.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    item.addClass("loading");
    $(".box a").fadeIn();
    thumb.fadeOut();
            $(".selected").width(230);
    $(".selected").height(129);
    item.addClass("selected");
    var url = this.href + " .content";
 item.addClass("loading");
 infoBox.css({
    "visibility": "hidden",
"height": "auto"
 });

infoBox.load(url, function () {
var newHeight = infoBox.outerHeight(true);

item.css({
    width: 692,
    height: newHeight
});
infoBox.animate({
    width: 692,
    height: newHeight
}, function () {
    $('#container').isotope('reLayout', function(){
    item.removeClass("loading");
    infoBox.css({"visibility": "visible"});
    var videoSpan = infoBox.find("span.video");
    var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
            'frameborder' : 0,
            'width' : '692',
            'height' : '389',
            'src' : 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ videoSpan.data("vimeoid") +'?autoplay=0&api=1'
    });
    videoSpan.replaceWith(iframe);
});
});
 });
});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a menu system, you can do this:

```
$('.menu a').on('click', function() {
  $('.box').eq($(this).index()).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

The animation is easy to do, so you can implement it.

Comment: i need to be able to actually click on a box, it's not a ul list, basically that plain html mark up i posted, i need to be able to click on each box and expand while closing previously expanded one.

Comment: But if you hide the box, how can you click on it?

Comment: i haven't said hide, i said close :)

Comment: `"display: none;` hides the box. There must be some other way of making the boxes appear, no?

Comment: if i provide .show() tho it will take display:none to visible, that isn't the difficulty, i'm only looking for a general loop to be able to click on a box, define it as "selected" and therefore "open it" while making the other "not selected" and "close them". By open it i mean animate it to a fix height and width and by closing i mean take back original heigth and width values

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to close your 's... you're opening 6 times now.

Are you looking for something like this: http://jsbin.com/uwoxur ??

To find the open box you can do this: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

```
$(".box:visible").doWhatYouWant();
```

Comment: thing is if you open one you need to close the other accordingly

Comment: yep, i have tried to apply it to what i need check updated question code